Регулярное выражение для роутинга в PHP
Есть в роутинге такая регулярка
'(favourites/([0-9]+))$|favourites' => 'page/favourites/$2',
Она говорит о том что если перейти по адресу
www.site.ru/favourites/19/ - к примеру
То в переменную залетит моя цифра 19!
А как сделать так чтобы я мог добраться до этого
www.site.ru/favourites/19/31/56/ - к примеру
Как модернизировать регулярку так чтобы я мог добираться до этих чисел
'favourites/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)' => 'page/favourites/$1/$2', - такой вариант рабочий но он не подходит так как в этом варианте эти переменные должны быть заполнены принудительно(РОУТИНГ ТАК НАСТРОЕН)
'(favourites/([0-9]+))$|favourites' => 'page/favourites/$2',

Нужно добраться именно до следующих чисел 19 31 56

Не понимаю зачем в вашем последнем примере начинается со скобки и уж тем более зачем заканчивается такой дикостью после $. Может объясните за маршрут без даты? Круглые скобки — служат своего рода группой для создания переменных, которые потом, во второй части выражения можно получить по $1 и т.д  favourites/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) будет в основании, а на конце page/favourites/$1/$2/$3И, вам не мешало бы воспользоваться каким-нибудь подходящим для тестирования сайтом. Например тыц

Ваш вариант работает без спору - но проблема в том что в вашем варианте нужно обязательно передавать параметры $1 $2 $3 - а в моем нет - и мне нужно чтобы я мог их получить, но они не были бы обязательными если их нету я все равно перейду на страницу /favourites

"в вашем варианте нужно обязательно передавать параметры". А о чём по вашему мои вопросы о задачах текущей маршрутизации, которую вы даже не соизволили описать? Не понимая вашей задачи писать советы по роутингу? Ну например — 'favourites\/?(.+)\/?' тоже может полностью решить вашу задачу за счёт одной переменной $1 и explode() качестве обработки даты. Сильно помогло?
